# List ExtJS 4 custom namespace in JSDuck documentation

Tags: extjs, jsduck

ExxtJS 4
JSDuck 6

I have an ExtJS workspace (MyWS) with a number of ExtJS apps (i.e. MyApp).
There is an overrides folder in the workspace (MyWS.overrides).

The 'Ext', 'MyApp' and 'MyWS' namespaces are listed in the left panel of the JSDuck html documentation, but the 'MyWS.overrides' namespace is not.

How can I get the 'MyWS.overrides' namespace listed?

```
Config file: 

{
"--": [
    "MyApp/app",
    "overrides",
    "packages/MyPackage/src",
    "ext/src"
],
"--ext-namespaces": "Ext,MyApp,MyWS,MyWS.overrides",
"--warnings": "-all:ext/src",
"--output": "docs",
"--css": [
    ".class-categories .section div {min-width: 250px; margin-right: 35px; width: auto !important;}"
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--ext-namespaces` option has nothing to do with listing namespaces in the left-side tree. This option is provided for cases where you have aliased ExtJS, so that instead of `Ext.define()` you're using `MyApp.define()` and other stuff like that and you'd like JSDuck to recognize this syntax.

The left-side tree only lists top-level variables, `MyWS.overrides` should naturally be placed inside `MyWS`. But it seems that this namespace only contains overrides, which aren't separately listed in docs - instead they are merged into the classes to which the override applies.

See also: https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck/wiki/@override

Comment: To sum up: overriding classes don't show up in the doc directly, they are merged into the class they override?